# Cannot initialize a variable of type'CFDictionaryRef' in XCode 4.6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

i'm writing an iPhoneApp that will record sound from a device through the audio Jack, I tried compiling my code but it keep saying

'Cannot initialize a variable of type'CFDictionaryRef'(aka 'const_CFDictionary*') with an lvalue of type 'const void*'
Here is part of my Code:

```
#pragma mark Audio session callbacks_______________________


// Audio session callback function for responding to audio route changes. If playing
//      back application audio when the headset is unplugged, this callback pauses  
//      playback and displays an alert that notifies the user that power has been      terminated.
//
//      The system takes care of iPod audio pausing during route changes--this callback
//      is not involved with pausing playback of iPod audio.
void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (
                                       void                      *inUserData,
                                       AudioSessionPropertyID    inPropertyID,
                                       UInt32                    inPropertyValueSize,
                                       const void                *inPropertyValue
                                       ) {

// ensure that this callback was invoked for a route change
if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;

// This callback, being outside the implementation block, needs a reference to the
//      MainViewController object, which it receives in the inUserData parameter.
//      You provide this reference when registering this callback (see the call to
//      AudioSessionAddPropertyListener).
MaxViewController *controller = (__bridge MaxViewController *) inUserData;

// if application sound is not playing, there's nothing to do, so return.
if (controller.sound.playing == 0 ) {

    NSLog (@"Audio route change while application audio is stopped.");
    return;

} else {

    // Determines the reason for the route change, to ensure that it is not     //      because of a category change.

    CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = inPropertyValue;

    CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef =
    CFDictionaryGetValue (
                          routeChangeDictionary,
                          CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason)
                          );

    SInt32 routeChangeReason;
```

I've searched every possible result here in stackoverflow and elsewhere but it has proven abortive. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = (CFDictionaryRef)inPropertyValue;`

Comment: Don't forget to add according frameworks (probably `AVFoundation` and `AudioToolbox`) and import their headers.